# How to set limits of integration for joint distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Assume you have a headache and you take two painkillers, x and y. To determine the probability that your headache comes back within three hours, we solve

$P(X<3, Y<3)=\int_{y=0}^{3}\int_{x=0}^{3}f_{X, Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$

So far, so good. The next question though is, what if you take painkiller y only after x stops working? In the textbook, this is given as $P(X+Y<3)=\int_{x=0}^{3}\int_{y=0}^{x-3}f_{X, Y}(x,y)dy\,dx$.

Can someone explain where the limits of integration come from in the second example? It would have made sense to me to set up the limits of x from 0 to x (the working period of the first pain killer) and for y, from x to 3 (since the second is taken after the first one stops working). So $P(X+Y<3)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{x}^{3}f_{X, Y}(x,y)dy\,dx$. Why is this wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both integration limits for $P(X+Y<3)$ are wrong.

The solution given by the texbook should be

$$P(X+Y<3)=\int_0^3\left[\int_0^{3-x}f(x,y)dy   \right]dx$$

or alternavively

$$P(X+Y<3)=\int_0^3\left[\int_0^{3-y}f(x,y)dx   \right]dy$$

this because you are integrating over a triangle...a drawing can help:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't really understand what integrating over a triangle means. As for the limits, why is x allowed to go from 0 to 3 but y from 0 to x-3, why is x-3 the upper limit? So the first painkiller works for 3 hours and the second one for x-3 hours? How does this mean that x+y<3? This is what I don't understand... My intuition would be that once the working period of painkiller x ends, y is taken, so the limits of y should be something like 3-x and 3, not 0 and 3-x.

Comment: @Joanna : the drawing is exactly to explain you which is the region to be integrated for $P(X+Y<3)$. If you take the second pil only after X stops working it is evident that $X \in (0;3]$ and $Y$ is in the remainig time.... $3-x$

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks!